# Fixed positioning for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

On the mobile site I'm building, I need the top header to stay fixed positioned.

I am aware of the fixed position solution for Mobile Safari as seen here:

http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

I tried it and it works well. However, I was wondering if there's a single solution that works for all major smartphone's mobile browsers. Note: I don't need the footer to stay fixed, just the top header. So this should make it easier accommodating for all mobile screen sizes since I'd be just setting the div's top to 0 onScroll.

Thanks!

Comment: Also keep in mind that Mobile Safari on iOS 5 supports `position: fixed`.

Comment: aha Jin, fixed positioning is working fine now

Answer (score 6):

**Important update**

As of iOS 5, fixed positioning works fine on mobile. Similarly latest androids support it.

---

**Old answer**

I think [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) is the most actively developed solution, it does support [Android](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-gets-android-1-5-compatibility)

But there are a few things to watch out for:

1. By enabling this hack you are disabling features people are used to like zoom.
2. It is adding a lot of complexity to your solution.

For these reasons JQtouch decided [not to use it](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=85):

> Not a problem. It is not currently
>   supported in jQTouch. Not sure how
>   familiar you are, but the main problem
>   here is that mobile Safari does not
>   support position: fixed. A few people
>   have worked on implementations of 
>   this, most notably
>   [Cubiq](http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch/5)
>    and 
>   [Doctyper](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/).
>   Both feel wrong to me, 
>   hence why I don't do by default, but
>   you're free to try to make an
>   extension which supports it-

Personally when dealing with stuff that needs fixed positioning on an iPhone I prefer to go with static positioning and just autoscroll to the bottom/top when changing the content dynamically.

Comment: Note that as of july 2011, iScroll does actually support pinch/zoom.

Comment: how do websites like  http://www.wikia.com/Wikia get a perfect fixed piece on the bottom? I've seen it on fixya.com too

Comment: @Sam iScroll4 now available with updates/fixes to the problems you mention http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem for more than two weeks . And this solution worked for me. Just include

**-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;**

in the css of the element along with position:fixed .

It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the link that Sam Saffron posted, it seems that a new version of iScroll (version 4) has resolved some of the problems Sam listed.

[iScroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

> In addition to all previous iScroll features, version 4 introduces:
>
> - Pinch / Zoom
> - Pull up/down to refresh
> - Improved speed and momentum
> - Snap to element
> - Customizable scrollbars

I have only looked at the demos on their site, so I can't vouch for it, but it looks good!